# Can the below my example will be dependency or composition in UML?

Tags: dependencies, uml, composition

I have question regarding compositon/agregation/dependency in UML.

1. I have service class AssociateDetailsService. In this AssociateDetailsService class,I am creating the instance of DAO as below.

AssociateDAO assDAO = new AssociateDAO();
so, since i am creating new instance , is it a composition relation here?
Here I am not sure DAO is owned by service class.

2. I have single ton class ConnectionFactory. In the DAO, I am getting the single ton instance . so Can i use dependency or composition here?

In DAO getting singleton instance of 
ConnectionFactory as below.

Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();

Can you please clarify here

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

"Dependency" in general in this case we believe.

[image]

We presume that these models do not have Instances as attributes. But if they do, using "association" would be a way in general (not "dependency).
And I believe the relation from DAO to ConnectorFactory should not be "Composition" at least according to the specification below (You might have read it though - page.36 of [UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/)

---

AggregationKind is an enumeration of the following literal values:

- none

Indicates that the property has no aggregation.

- shared

Indicates that the property has a shared aggregation.

- composite

Indicates that the property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed objects (parts).

Semantic Variation Points

Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler. The order and way in which part instances are created is not defined.

---

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules on how code should be translated into UML (or the other way around), but in general I think that:

- If your class A has an **attribute** of type B then there is definitely an association. Whether this should be a composition, aggregation or just a plain association depends on the actual required behavior, and even the functional meaning of the association. (I wrote an [article](http://bellekens.com/2010/12/20/uml-composition-vs-aggregation-vs-association/) about these differences on my website if you want to know more about that)
- If your class A only instantiates a **variable** of type B during the execution of a method then you probably have a dependency.

Comment: Thanks Geert  for reply. But I saw in many forums - if we are instantiating class B using new inside class A, then that is composition. beacsue the life cycle of b is controlled by A here. eg: Public class A{  public method A{  B b = new B()}.so is it not composition?

Comment: @vjk When the relation is not part of the structure, but only exists during behavior execution then it is usually not considered  an association.